# HTTP Post Call from one Salesforce org to another not working

Tags: apex, rest

I have two Salesforce orgs connected and I am trying to pass a created Opportunity from one to the other using Apex REST callouts. Everything seems to be connected properly because when I test with a "GET" method, I get a successful HTTP code (200).

The receiving org's code is very simple (still in the proof of concept stage so not much here just to see if it passes through correctly).

```
@HttpPost
global static ID postOpp(String name) {
    Opportunity o = new Opportunity(
    name = name);

    o.closedate = date.newInstance(2020,10,10);
    o.stagename = 'Qualification';
    o.accountID = '0015x000026OM6g';       
    
    insert o;
    return o.Id;
}
```

When I use workbench, and test a POST request in this org, I see it is successful and the opp is created. Now I am trying to send an opp from my other Salesforce org. I've tried setting the body a few different ways but nothing seems to be working.

```
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('callout:HS_Integration');
    request.setMethod('POST');
    
    JSONGenerator j = JSON.createGenerator(true);
    j.writeStartObject();
    j.writeStringField('Name', 'test cm 4');
    j.writeEndObject();
    String jsonS = j.getAsString();
    
    request.setBody(jsonS);
    
    response = http.send(request);
```

I don't think anything is wrong with my authorization or named credentials because of the successful HTTP code. As you can see I try using setBody() with a basic JSON string, I've also tried it with a much simpler string I saw some people use ('name=TestOpp'), but the opp is not getting created in the target org. How am I supposed to use setBody to pass over information correctly? Can someone explain what I may be missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When using automatic parameters, there's a top-level "request" object you need to pass in. Your code should look like:

```
String body = JSON.serialize(
  new Map<String, Object> {
    'request' => new Map<String, Object> {
      'name' => 'test cm 4'
    }
  }
);
request.setBody(body);
```

Also note that the parameters are case-sensitive; you cannot use `Name` instead of `name`.

The payload should look like:

```
{ "request": { "name": "test cm 4" } }
```

You may also find the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_methods.htm) helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code snippet instead of what I had for the body and I still am getting a 200 return code but I am not seeing the opportunity created in my org. If that json body is in the right format do you have any other ideas on what could be missing?

Comment: I'm starting to think the issue isn't with my body but with my named credential. Right now my credential URL is 'https://myorg.salesforce.com/' and my callout is directly to that, but do I need to append something to my request.setEndpoint() to point directly to the Opportunity service? 
I've tried request.setEndpoint('callout:HS_Integration/services/apexrest');
but that didn't work either, I got an invalid session error.

clearly I am connected to my target org in some way but maybe I am not pointing to the opportunity services. Any idea?

Comment: @user88797 It would be `callout:HS_Integration/services/apexrest/urlFragment` (where `urlFragment` is the `urlResource='/urlFragment'` in the RestResource annotation). P.S. Why not just use the normal Salesforce REST API at this point?

Comment: Hi sfdcfox, 

In my target orgs RestResource class I defined it as just this:

"@RestResource(urlMapping='/Opportunity/*')"

but when I change my endpoint to 

"request.setEndpoint('callout:HS_Integration/services/apexrest/Opportunity');"

I get this error:
"14:21:46:327 USER_DEBUG [38]|DEBUG|[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]"

But when I omit everything after HS_integration I get a successful HTTP code. any idea why?

Comment: @user88797 Because you're reaching the base login URL. If your session is invalid, check your OAuth settings on your Named Credential. You need to make sure you're connected.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what I'm checking specifically? My Named Credential is hooked up to an Authentication Provider that I set up for it and I did everything pretty standard based on tutorials.